# CenterVertical textView in RelativeLayout in android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/current_task_status_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:clickable="true"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_finish"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="ЗАВЕРШИТЬ"
    android:textColor="#2a2a2a"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="17sp"
    android:textColor="#626262"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    tools:text="22:34:21"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So i want all my textViews to be centerVectival. bottom_sheet_finish is beggier, so it height enought and fill all RelativeLayout, but bottom_sheet_time is small. In android 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 everything is fine, but in 4.1.2 bottom_sheet_time is in left top corner, i tried different combinations of layout_gravity,  layout_centerParent and soon, but it is still in right top corner. Help, please

Comment: What happens when you make the height of RelativeLayout to match_parent?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi , i need this view to be wrap_content

Comment: Ok just add android:layout_gravity="center" to RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

To center vertically all your `TextView's` either make your `RelativeLayout's` height to match_parent and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to the first `TextView`

Or

Add `android:layout_gravity="center"` to `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/current_task_status_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_finish"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="ЗАВЕРШИТЬ"
        android:textColor="#2a2a2a"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"

        android:lineSpacingExtra="17sp"
        android:textColor="#626262"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        tools:text="22:34:21" />
</LinearLayout>
```